# Slide in elements from bottom to top when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know there are already a lot of this kind of questions, but i want to use a totally different animation.

See example: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/OnScrollEffectLayout/

I would like to use something simple and everything what i would like to have is that instead the elements are coming from left or right side, they would slide in from bottom to top.

The nearest tutorial to what i want is that one, but i want to use it on 4, 3 and 2 rows of boxes. And that one is only designed for 2 rows.

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/DjmJe

Comment: That animation is comming by CSS: `.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}` If you want to do that effect with responsive design I think you have to append the modules after measuring the width available and then add that animation with proportional to the index of each module, probably wrapped in a parent div in each line.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of sass magic, that codepen can be modified to allow any number of columns.  I added a $columns variable, and then changed the widths and nth-childs to be based off the variable.

```
$columns : 4;
* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box); 
}

section {
  background: #eee;
  max-width: 300px * $columns;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module {
  width: 100% / $columns - 2%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 8% / $columns;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  &:nth-child( #{$columns}n + #{$columns} ) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(black, 0.2);
}

body {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/3/blurry-blue.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 30px;
}

.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(#{$columns}n + #{$columns}) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}

@keyframes come-in {
  to { transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

http://codepen.io/bhlaird/pen/KLGEx